# How to postion a Div in the flow after a scaled Svg (without JS)?

Tags: css, html, svg, viewbox

I want to position a DIV just after a dynamically scaled SVG.
Unfortunately the DIV position doesn't change.

```
<svg style="transform:scale(x); transform-origin:0 0"></svg>
<div>Sould be just under the SVG whatever scale</div>
```

I've tried different techniques (`position:relative`, `flex-direction:column`, `fit-content`, ...) without success. I have to recalculate the DIV position after every scaling.

Is it possible to achieve this in CSS, whith no Javascript ?

```js
Transform.onclick = function () {  
  scale = function ( ratio ) {
    S1.style.transform = 'scale(' + ratio + ')'
  
    //the calculation part I'd like to avoid
    var ty =  S1.height.baseVal.value * ( ratio - 1 ) 
    DivIn.style.transform = 'translateY(' + ty + 'px)'
  }
  
  toggle( this )
}

Dims.onclick = function () {  
  var H = S1.height.baseVal.value
  var W = S1.width.baseVal.value

  scale = function ( ratio ) {
    S1.setAttribute( "height", H * ratio )
    S1.setAttribute( "width", W * ratio )
  }
  
  toggle( this )
}

Symb.onclick = function () {     
  scale = function ( ratio ) {
    S1.style.fontSize = ratio + "em"
  }
  
  toggle( this )
}

Transform.click()

function toggle ( button ) {
  Array.from( document.querySelectorAll( 'button' ) )
  .forEach( b => b.style.fontWeight = button==b ? 700:500 )
}
```

```css
svg {
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
div#DivOut {
  position: relative;
}
div#Container {
  position: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: fit-content;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<input type=number value=1 oninput="scale(this.value)">
<button id=Transform>1: Transform</button> 
<button id=Dims>2: Relative Height</button> 
<button id=Symb>3: Symbol</button> 

<div id=Container>
  <svg width=50 height=50 id=S1>
    <use xlink:href="#SY"></use>
    <symbol id=SY>
      <rect x=0 y=0 width=100% height=100% fill=red />
    </symbol>
  </svg>
  <div id=DivIn>Next line test 1</div>
</div>
<div id=DivOut>Next line test 2</div>
```

Comment: It would require you to wrap the other content in a tag, which you translateY depending on the `svg` scale. Even then, it would require JS, because that's the way you are handling your `svg` scaling.

Comment: @Ricky_Ruiz yes but I would need to make a calculation of the Y translation, isn't it? If true it's was I would like to avoid (if possible)

Comment: Yeah, then you should consider changing to `width` and `height`, to force browser redrawing. Al though it is not recommended and using `transform` is almost always better performance-wise, what you want to achieve is not possible without doing what I stated above, or using other JS solutions.

Comment: @Ricky_Ruiz I've updated my code snippet with what you suggested. I will keep with that solution if I find nothing better. Thank you.

Comment: Hopefully, if not, another approach could be using a `<symbol>` along with the `<use>` tag to be able to change the size of the `<svg>` with the `font-size` property, set `font-size: 50px;` to parent, and change the values with `em` units in its child. Ex. 2 em = scale(2),  it will still cause reflow, but it may have better performance than `width` and `height`. You can evaluate this performance in DevTools on the Timeline tab.

Comment: @Ricky_Ruiz this last solution seems interesting but I don't know how to implement it. I will update the snippet with it.

Comment: Enclose the <svg>…</svg> content within its own <div> tags. Then its just one div followed by another, the first one holding your svg content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I found is to set a `viewBox` attribute to the `<svg>` element.

Then you can resize it by just changing the width and height via CSS style.

```js
function resize()
{
    SVG1.classList.toggle( 'double' )
}
```

```css
.double {
   width: 200px ;
   height: 200px ;
}
```

```html
<svg id=SVG1 viewBox="0 0 100 100"  width=100 height=100>  
   <rect x=0 y=0 width=100 height=100 fill=red />
</svg>
<div>
  <button onclick="resize()">Resize</button>
</div>
```